# Troubleshoot NoClassDefFoundError in Java

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have a Java program called Main.java, it is located in the following directory:

```
/home/user/program/Main.java
```

When I try to run Main.java from the 'program' directory, everything goes ok, I use this line:

```
/home/user/program$ java Main
```

But when I try to run Main.java from the home directory :

```
/home$ java /home/user/program/Main
```

I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /home/user/program/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.user.program.Main
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: can you post the code of you main class

Comment: @svrist OP says it does work.
@shaw try setting class path `java -cp /home/user/program Main`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to your classpath, which will default to the current directory. When you run `java Main` from `/home/user/program` it finds the class in the current directory (since the package seems to be unset, meaning it is the default). Hence, it finds the class in `/home/user/program/Main.class`.

Running `java /home/user/program/Main` from `/home` tries to find the class in the classpath (the current directory) which will look in `/home/home/user/program` expecting to find the file `Main.class` containing a definition of the `Main` class with package `.home.user.program`.

> **Extra detail**: I think the java
>   launcher is trying to be nice by
>   converting /-notation for a classname
>   to the .-notation; and when you run
>   `java /home/user/program/Main` it is
>   actually running `java
>   .home.user.program.Main` for you. This
>   is because you shouldn't be specifying
>   a file, but a fully specified
>   classname (ie including package
>   specifier). And when a class has a package
>   java expects to find that class within a 
>   directory structure that matches the package
>   name, inside a directory (or jar) in the 
>   classpath; hence, it will try to look in
>   `/home/home/user/program` for the class file

You can fix it by specifying your classpath with `-cp` or `-classpath`:

```
java -cp /home/user/program Main
```

Comment: If you have a package defined you may need to do this:  `java -cp /home/user/program:. Main`  The extra `:.` means "and the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

Because its looking for the class using the fullname you give (/home/user/program/Main). You should only look for the Main class but using the good classpath :
java Main -cp /home/user/program

Which means it'll search the Main class in the given set of paths

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd command version does not know where to find the classes.
You need to provide the so called classpath

```
/home$ java -cp userprogram Main
```

Comment: `-cp user/program` I guess :)

Comment: Right - I saw /home/user as the home directory

Answer (score 0):

Because of what you say I conclude this:

- Main is in "top" (root) package

And when you execute java you must indicate the classpath, it is, the root directory where your pakage and classes structure is located.

In your case it is the very /home/user/program. And I guess your classpath is defined as "." (the dir you are located at). When you call java from home the classpath is being taken erroneosly.

If you want to call your main using a different package declare the package at the top of the class:

```
package user.program;
```

And set the classpath to /home (or execute java from that dir).
Next call java this way:

```
java user.program.Main
```

using dots because its a full class name (indicating packages). That is translated to dirs concatenating classpath + package + class. By example:

```
/home
user.program -> user/program/
Main         -> Main.class
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the info, this made me understand more what does a classpath mean

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you call `java /home/user/program/Main` the package `Main` is in is meant to be `home.user.program`, which I assume is not true for `Main` (I assume it's in the default package, i.e. none at all). Is there a `package` declaration at the top of `Main`?

I'd suggest to use the classpath suggestions in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

java -cp /home/user/program Main

Answer (score 0):

just a while ago faced this kind of error of (NoClassDefFoundError). I imported some third party library in my android app using eclipse env. I got this error during a runtime - some class from this third party library couldn't be found and a result of this NoClassDefFoundError was thrown, despite the mentioned library correctly appeared in classpath, so I really didn't know what else can be done to solve this problem. 
While playing with ***"Order and Export"*** tab within "Java Build Path", I put my imported third party library *to the top of the list of all libraries in my project and checked its checkbox* - this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same error when trying to compile and run it. The book, "Head First Java" explains and addresses this problem appropriately. Here is a screenshot from the book for your reference.

[image: A screenshot from Head First Java about how to compile and run a java program by including package names.]

Hope its helpful.