# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main in Eclipse on OSX 10.6

Tags: eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, java

When i try to run a simple hello world application in eclipse i get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I've compiled my class with the javac tool installed on this computer and ran it without a problem. This leads me to believe it should work with the JDK installed on this computer.
I'm running OSX 10.6, Eclipse Indigo SR2 and i have the 1.6.0JDK installed which apparently is the standard for OSX. The build path is pointing to the correct location for this JDK.

I've also tested it in XCode and it also worked without a problem. Still i'd rather use Eclipse as a IDE scince i'm working parallel to a team developing an app for windows (i have to make some minor tweaks to the app to solve some dependency issues on OSX) and they use Eclipse. Also it's what i'm used to and some familiarity is nice when you have to work in an OS you've been using or just two days :-D

How could i solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does your project have any Build Path errors?

Comment: mmm are you sure that the classpath that you use when you compile it is the same as when you execute it?
NoClassDefFoundError means that when you compiled that class the javac can found the Main class...while when you execute it, it miss...so it seems that you miss some JAR when you execute it

Comment: i've found out what i did wrong. I checked the run configuration and apparently there was a class named "Main" specified as the Main class. Scince it did not exist it could not be found. I changed the main class to the class containing the main method and now it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! (i would post this as an answer but i don't have enough Rep to do it XD )

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError , Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376311/noclassdeffounderror-java)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Thanks to your comment @Frank Vanbever, I found out that the "run" was not configured as "run as an Android application" anymore. I don't know why though, I can't remember having changed those parameters recently... Menu "Run > Run As > Android Application" worked. You made my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting the workspace** worked for me.