# Could not find com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenuActivity.apk

Tags: android

I am trying to make use of the SlidingMenu Library for Android but I get these errors:

```
Could not find com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenuActivity.apk
```

and another error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24767): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
```

I have properly added the `com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenuActivity` to the Java Build section.

Comment: There are many solutions to this error defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk

Comment: I have updated the Project properties to use the Jar but now i have this issue:
E/AndroidRuntime(24767): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu

Comment: make sure there is a /libs/ directory in your project, and copy and paste the library jar into it.

Comment: Do note that tags stand alone, and combining them does not create a unique term.  For example, combining `sliding`, `menu` and `library` does not mean you are talking about a sliding menu library.

Comment: i followed edthethird and now the issue is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.R$styleable

Answer (score 3):

What I found is that some time between June 2012 and now (August 2013) the package name changed.  Performing a global search-and-replace of `com.slidingmenu.lib` to `com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshoot Android 'Could not find somelibrary.apk'**

[Could not find Library.apk!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

**Troubleshoot Android 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.somelibrary.mylibrary'**

[Troubleshoot NoClassDefFoundError in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376311/noclassdeffounderror-java)