# No Class Def Found Error

Tags: java, grails, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a Grails application which generates `pdf` and `doc` files. I am using  `jasper report` and `iReport` to export reports in pdf and doc formats. When I try to download pdf, the following internal server error occurs:

```
Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.
```

What could be the possible reason, I am unable to figure out. I found  some similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them resolved my issue.

Trying to resolve the issue from last day but not get any success.Any one please give some suggestion/solution I have lots of hope from this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue:

```
Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.
```

occured due to many factors as listed in answers.In my application problem occured due to corrupted fonts.My issue is resolved when I added jar(s) of the legitimate fonts(which my application uses) on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

> Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Message

As per the javadocs:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

It means that classes in not found during the execution. So you need to have the jar containing this class on your `classpath` while running your program.

In your case, I believe you are missing the jasperreports jar on the classpath as `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser`, is conatinined in `jasperreports.jar`

Comment: I have already included the required jar file jasperreports-4.5.0.jar But still problem exists.

Comment: @Abdullah where have u added that jar? and how are u running your code?

Comment: I have added jar in lib folder of my App.

Comment: I am running my Appp on port 80.

Comment: @Abdullah So you are running the code as a webapp, then check under your war file WEB-INF/lib, whether the jar is there.

Comment: No, in WEB-INF there is no lib folder.

Comment: @Abdullah that is your problem, for a web application, the related jars should be under WEB-INF/lib folder. Create the folder and put the jars there, redeploy application, and share the good news.

Comment: lib folder is parallel to web-app dir.

Comment: @Abdullah that lib folder belongs to your development environment and not part of your webapplication war file. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Abdullah have u tried adding the lib to WEB-INF/lib and redploying your appilcation?

Comment: @JunedAhsan You realise this is a Grails app yeah? WEB-INF/lib isn't the place to put jars when developing

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have the required jasperreports jar in the classpath? If not, adding the jar to the classpath should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

basically means:

> Everything was okay at compilation/packaging, but at runtime the
>   class(class definition) could not be found.

This can happen when you compile your code against correct dependencies but at run time some of them are missing from classpath. For some troubleshooting you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376311/troubleshoot-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)